# Ionic 3 http request

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ionic3

Whenever http request (using rxjs) is made from a real device at that time origin and the referrer received into service is undefined.

Http request does not work as expected from real device.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class DbcallService {
  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  getData() {
    var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    this._http.get(url).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: No.Can you show the `code`?

Comment: Its simple rxjs get request.

Comment: How simple is it? If you need to have answer you need to show the code.Please see this too: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please find code in question.

Comment: can you add your network call in here when using a browser? for checking origin on a real device you can connect Charles proxy.

Comment: ok i will try those

Answer (score 0):

You have to change it as shown below.

*your-provider.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DbcallService {
  constructor(private _http: Http) {
  }

  getData() {
    var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    this._http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

When you called it, you have to do like below.

*my-page.ts*

```
this.myProvider.getData().subscribe(
      result => {
       },
      error => { },
      () => { }
    );
```

Comment: It's passing origin when it's run from browser. but when it's run as application in android device.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you? can you access your URL using `Postman`? If yes then you can access from the device too.

Comment: Yes i am able to access url but in request its not passing origin or referrer.

Comment: Its not passing origin or referrer to api server.

Comment: It seems you need to `post` the data no? not `get`?

Comment: No its get request to receive data.

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpClient instead for Angular 6.

This works:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DbcallService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getData() {
    var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    this._http.get(url).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```